# Embedding cg shaders in C++ GPGPU library

Tags: c++, embed, shader, cg

I'm writing a GPGPU Fluid simulation, which runs using C++/OpenGL/Cg.  At the moment, the library requires that the user specify a path to the shaders, which is will then read it from.

I'm finding it extremely annoying to have to specify that in my own projects and testing, so I want to make the shader contents linked in with the rest.

Ideally, my .cg files would still be browsable seperately, but a post-build step or pre-processor directive would include it in the source when required.

To make things slightly more annoying, I have a "utils" shader file, which contains functions that are shared among things (like converting 3d texture coords to the 2d atlas equivalent).

I'd like a solution that's cross platform if possible, but it's not so big a deal, as it is currently windows-only. My searches have only really turned up `objcopy` for linux, but using that for windows is less than ideal.

If it helps, the project is available at http://code.google.com/p/fluidic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want the shaders embedded as strings in your binary? I'm not aware of any cross-platform tools/libraries to do that, which isn't that surprising because the binaries will be different formats.

For Windows it sounds like you want to store them as a [string resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_%28Windows%29). You can then read the string using [`LoadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647486%28VS.85%29.aspx). [Here's how to add them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xhwfctz%28VS.80%29.aspx), but it doesn't look like you can link them to a file.

A particularly hacky but cross-platform solution might be to write a script to convert your shaders into a string constant in a header. Then you can just `#include` it in your code.

I.e. you have the file `myshader.shader` which contains:

```
int aFunction(int i, int j)
{
   return i/j;
}
```

And you have a build step that creates the file `myshader.shader.h` which looks like:

```
const char[] MYSHADER_SHADER =
"int aFunction(int i, int j)"
"{"
"   return i/j;"
"}";
```

Then add `#include "myshader.shader.h"` to your code.

Very hacky, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work (except for maybe length/space limits on string literals).

Update: With the release of G++ 4.5 it supports C++0x raw string literals. These can contain new lines [4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2053.html). I haven't tested it but you should be able to do something like this:

```
const char[] MY_SHADER = R"qazwsx[
#include "my_shader.c"
]qazwsx";
```

I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for a less hacky solution than the header file generation method.

It's a real pain to have the shaders as a string resource, because I lose all my syntax hightlighty goodness, and the ability to use `cgc` to check for compile errors (without copy/pasting into another file, of course).

May have to accept there's no way of doing this nicely, and go with the hack.