# Including files as raw string literals

Tags: c++, c++11, include, string-literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++, can you #include a file into a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246301/c-c-can-you-include-a-file-into-a-string-literal)

Is it possible to get the entire contents of a text file as a string at compile time using C++11 raw string literals?

Basically, I want to be able to embed GLSL shader source files without having to modify them.

The following approach is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485503/embedding-cg-shaders-in-c-gpgpu-library):

```
const std::string shaderSource = R"glsl(
  #include "my_shader.glsl"
  )glsl";
```

It's hacky, but it'd be fine for my application. However, this doesn't seem to work due to raw string literals being evaluated before file inclusion.

I suppose I could move the `'R"glsl('` and `')glsl"'` parts to the beginning and end of each shader source file instead, and then just do this:

```
const std::string shaderSource =
  #include "my_shader.glsl"
  ;
```

But like I said, I'd really prefer not having to modify the shader source files as that would complicate run-time loading of the same files and therefore make them less portable.